# How can I show Subset from multiple model in Django Custom View with the UI same as other models?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have created a Custom view in Admin Panel with this code in admin.py. I want the sometemplate.html template to have the information in the same UI format just like when I click on another model in the admin panel, and that information needs to be a combination of rows from multiple models. So, the data is displayed in this custom view will have all the entries from multiple models with valid = False

How can I do that in my custom view of Django admin?

```
class DummyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = DummyModel
    
    def my_custom_view(self,request):
        # return HttpResponse('Admin Custom View')
        context = dict(
            )
        return TemplateResponse(request, "webapp/sometemplate.html", context)

    def get_urls(self):
        view_name = '{}_{}_changelist'.format(
            self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name)
        return [
            path('my_admin_path/', self.my_custom_view, name=view_name),
        ]
admin.site.register(DummyModel, DummyModelAdmin)
```

sometemplate.html code:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you share your models? Does these models have the same columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) where you define one common base model, in their example `Project`, that is inherited by the models `ArtProject` and `ResearchProject`, and a queryset of the base model contains instances of the base model and all models that inherit from it. Example from the docs:

> ```
> >>> Project.objects.all()
> [ <Project:         id 1, topic "Department Party">,
>  <ArtProject:      id 2, topic "Painting with Tim", artist "T. Turner">,
>  <ResearchProject: id 3, topic "Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor "Dr. >Winter"> ]
> ```

It also provides some useful [model admin](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/admin.html) classes to display parent and child models in one list view. A lot of the django admin functionalities are preserved.

If you don't need any of that, you are probably better off writing the view on your own. Django admin is useful to bring some data fast to the screen, but it can get very complicated when you try to get around the default way of doing things.